# How can i get rid of overlaping textfield which is behind the keyboard in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I made a form which is 10 TextField inside ListView.
so when i'm going to input last two field the keyboard is appear above the TextField and instantly can't see what is inputed into TextField but can see after disappearing keyboard.

**Note: I'm using a ScreenUtils package**

**main.dart file**

```
 ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(375, 812),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
builder: (_,child){},
),
```

**form_field.dart**

```
Scaffold( body:ListView( physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(), childred:[], ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ListView with a Column widget and then add your TextField as children and then wrap your Column with SingleChildScrollView like this.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
       TextFormField(),
       TextFormField(),
)
```